# MyFragmentPagerAdapter displays the wrong data in a "weird" way, starts with data for position 1 at position 0, then only at position1 the rest

Tags: android

First of all, these problems don't only occur at my project, but also when I tried to implement the code, described at [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com). That makes it very mysterious to me. Problem: At the beginning, data for position 1 is displayed at position 0, so it's displaced by one. Then when I swipe back and forth, it behaves absolutely chaotic, an example:
 Swipe to position 1: Nothing is displayed.
 Swipe to position 2: Nothing is displayed.
Swipe back to position 1: Displays the right data;
Swipe to position 0 (nothing) and back to position 1: Now, data for pos 2 is displayed...

So alternating, data for any position is displayed at position 1, only there.

**The whole class where the adapter is set up:**

```
public class PhrasesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private String LOG_TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    private final String INTENT_KEY_LOADED_PHRASES = "loadedPhrases";

    @BindView(R.id.navView)
    NavigationView navView;

    @BindView(R.id.drawerLayout)
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @BindView(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @BindView(R.id.pager)
    ViewPager pager;

    private FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;
   // private ScreenSlidePagerAdapter adapterViewPager;

    private ArrayList<Phrase> loadedPhrases;

    private static ArrayList<Phrase> fragmentChapter1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<Phrase> fragmentChapter2 = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<Phrase> fragmentChapter3 = new ArrayList<>();

    private static ArrayList<Phrase> C1sC1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<Phrase> C1sC2 = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<Phrase> C1sC3 = new ArrayList<>();


    private List<Phrase> C2sC2;
    private List<Phrase> C2sC1;
    private List<Phrase> C2sC3;

    private List<Phrase> C3sC2;
    private List<Phrase> C3sC1;
    private List<Phrase> C3sC3;

    private List<Phrase> C4sC2;
    private List<Phrase> C4sC1;
    private List<Phrase> C4sC3;

    private List<Phrase> C5sC2;
    private List<Phrase> C5sC1;
    private List<Phrase> C5sC3;

    public String test = "test";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phrases);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        loadedPhrases = bundle.getParcelableArrayList(INTENT_KEY_LOADED_PHRASES);

        giveOutPhrases();






        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);


        adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        //adapterViewPager = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
       // pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

        //Log.v("PACKAGE: ", this.getPackageName());
        //Log.v("PACKAGE RESOURCE PATH: ", this.getPackageResourcePath());


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /*private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            Bundle args = new Bundle();

            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    args.putInt("testInt", position);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    args.putInt("testInt", position);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    args.putInt("testInt", position);
                    break;
            }
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, Integer.toString(position));

            ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }
    */

    public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        // Returns total number of pages
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;

        }

        // Returns the fragment to display for that page
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, Integer.toString(position));

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return PagerFragment.newInstance(0, "Page # 1", fragmentChapter1);
                case 1:
                    return PagerTwo.newInstance(1, "Page # 2", fragmentChapter2);
                case 2:
                    return PagerFragment.newInstance(2, "Page # 3", fragmentChapter3);
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        // Returns the page title for the top indicator
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Page " + position;
        }


    }


    private void giveOutPhrases() {


        for (Phrase entrie : loadedPhrases) {
            String phraseChapter = entrie.getChapter();
            String phraseSubChapter = entrie.getSubChapter();


            switch (phraseChapter) {

                case "FirstContacts":
                    if (phraseSubChapter.equals("MostImportant")) {
                        C1sC1.add(entrie);
                        // Log.v("C1sC1 now:", Integer.toString(C1sC1.size()));
                    }
                    if (phraseSubChapter.equals("Greeting")) {
                        C1sC2.add(entrie);
                    }

                    if (phraseSubChapter.equals("ToGetKnowOfSomeone")) {
                        C1sC3.add(entrie);
                    }
            }
        }

       // Log.v(LOG_TAG, "1:" + Integer.toString(C1sC1.size()));
        //Log.v(LOG_TAG, "2:" + Integer.toString(C1sC2.size()));
        //Log.v(LOG_TAG, "3:" + Integer.toString(C1sC3.size()));

        fragmentChapter1 = C1sC1;
        fragmentChapter2 = C1sC2;
        fragmentChapter3 = C1sC3;

    }

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

**The ViewPager:**

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp" />
    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
       app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**The adapter:**

```
     public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;

        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, Integer.toString(position));

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return PagerFragment.newInstance(0, "Page # 1", fragmentChapter1);
                case 1:
                    return PagerTwo.newInstance(1, "Page # 2", fragmentChapter2);
                case 2:
                    return PagerFragment.newInstance(2, "Page # 3", fragmentChapter3);
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Page " + position;
        }


    }

Fragment for swipes:

    public class PagerFragment extends Fragment implements PhraseAdapter.PhraseAdapterOnClickHandler {

    private final String LOG_TAG = "PAGERFRAGMENT";

    private String title;
    private int page;
    private ArrayList<Phrase> list;
    //private ArrayList<PhrasePairs> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
    private TextView testTv;



    RecyclerView recyclerView;


    public static PagerFragment newInstance(int page, String title, ArrayList<Phrase> list) {
        PagerFragment pagerFragment = new PagerFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("someInt", page);
        args.putString("someTitle", title);
        args.putParcelableArrayList("phraseList", list);
        pagerFragment.setArguments(args);

        Log.v("PAGEFRAGMENT:", "new Instance");
        return pagerFragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
        this.list = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("phraseList");
        //createPairs();


    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle){
        super.onActivityCreated(bundle);

       //Log.v(LOG_TAG, title+ " has:" + list.size() + "phrases");

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false);
        PhraseAdapter adapter = new PhraseAdapter(this);

        recyclerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewPhrases);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //adapter.setData(pairs);

       // Log.v(LOG_TAG,Integer.toString(pairs.size()));
       // Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onActivityCreated");        

        testTv = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.testTv);
        testTv.setText(title);

    }
```

**Its xml:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerviewPhrases"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code where you set the Viewpager adapter? Might give us more insight.

Comment: I have added the class.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

Problem is here:

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle){
        super.onActivityCreated(bundle);       

        recyclerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewPhrases);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);            

        adapter.setData(pairs);    

        testTv = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.testTv);
        testTv.setText(title);            

    }
```

I shouldn't have provide the views with data here, but in

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {}
```

so instead of:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager, container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle){
    super.onActivityCreated(bundle);

   //Log.v(LOG_TAG, title+ " has:" + list.size() + "phrases");

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false);
    PhraseAdapter adapter = new PhraseAdapter(this);

    recyclerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewPhrases);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //adapter.setData(pairs);

   // Log.v(LOG_TAG,Integer.toString(pairs.size()));
   // Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onActivityCreated");        

    testTv = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.testTv);
    testTv.setText(title);

}
```

it's:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager, container, false);


        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false);
        PhraseAdapter adapter = new PhraseAdapter(this);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewPhrases);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.setData(pairs);

        testTv = view.findViewById(R.id.testTv);
        testTv.setText(title);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle){
        super.onActivityCreated(bundle);

        /////No need for this callback
    }
```